# pgf's and pstricks's opacity is not appearing in .ps and .pdf files

Tags: 18.04, latex, texlive

I had recently upgraded my PC to Ubuntu 18.04 with TexLive 2017. The problem that came up is that the opacity of tikz (PGF) and of pstricks pictures is  not working (appearing) in .ps and .pdf files after rendering.

I've tried in Texstudio, Texmaker, and Kile and the problem occurred with all three editors. I've tried to evince and okular and the problem occurred in both viewers.

I suspect that the problem isn't caused by TexLive but by .ps and .pdf printing, because in Texstudio's preview and in Ktikz (Qtikz),  PGF images are rendering correctly.

Any ideas on how to handle this issue?

**edit:** @N0rbert. Here is a minimal example:
In Ktikz the code

```
\definecolor{zzwwqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.4,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-2.145506918452885,-1.325689276698863) rectangle (3.903912924143249,3.2296596894011578);
\fill[line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq,fill=zzwwqq,fill opacity=0.25] (0.,0.) -- (2.,0.) -- (2.,2.) -- (0.,2.) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=1.2pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.25] (1.,1.) circle (0.5cm);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (0.,0.)-- (2.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (2.,0.)-- (2.,2.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (2.,2.)-- (0.,2.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (0.,2.)-- (0.,0.);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives this picture (right):

> [image: Right]

and if complile the analog code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}

\begin{document}


\definecolor{zzwwqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.4,0.}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \clip(-2.145506918452885,-1.325689276698863) rectangle (3.903912924143249,3.2296596894011578);
    \fill[line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq,fill=zzwwqq,fill opacity=0.25] (0.,0.) -- (2.,0.) -- (2.,2.) -- (0.,2.) -- cycle;
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.25] (1.,1.) circle (0.5cm);
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (0.,0.)-- (2.,0.);
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (2.,0.)-- (2.,2.);
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (2.,2.)-- (0.,2.);
    \draw [line width=1.2pt,color=zzwwqq] (0.,2.)-- (0.,0.);
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

in Texstudio (or other editor)

gives this picture (wrong):

> [image: Wrong]

In the last picture opacity doesn't works.

Comment: Could you please provide minimal example to make it reproducible?

Comment: @N0rbert. I've edited my post and a minimal example has given. I hope it could be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On 16.04 LTS it renders normally in Gummi and QTikZ. I can't test on 18.04 LTS as I do not have TeXLive installed on it. Let's wait for reaction from other AU users :)

Comment: @N0rbert. Thanks. I'm using LaTeX,  tikz, pstricks, TexLive for years. I didn't have this problem in  all earlier Ubuntu LTS distributions. I think that this is a printing problem and perhaps it will be corrected in next  updates.

Comment: Perhaps this indication in Log file (Texmaker) could be useful: _"Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support fadings."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I asked the same question in TeX SE  and  was answered by [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1053/alexg). Assuming that some are interested about this issue, here is:
[pgf's and pstricks's opacity is not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453780/pgfs-and-pstrickss-opacity-is-not-working)